# Calculating 0% Interest?

Tags: javascript, html

Good evening! I'm teaching myself to code. Right now, I'm making a JavaScript loan calculator, but I hit a snag. If I put 0% interest, it displays nothing in my output textboxes. Everything else is working perfectly though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Loan Calculator</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
text-align: left;
    }

    .auto-style2 {
font-size: larger;
color: #FFF;
font: Georgia;
    }

    .auto-style3 {
width: 82px;
text-align: center;
style="float: right;
    }

    table {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #d2691e;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loaninfo">
 <div class="auto-style1">
        <p><strong>
          <span class="auto-style2"> </span></strong><strong><span class="auto-style2"><br />
        </span></strong></p>
    </div>
    <table width="327">
        <tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
        <tr>

 <td>Loan Amount:</td>
            <td>
                $
                <input type="text" name="principal" size="12" title="textfield" pattern="([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+"  >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Interest Rate:</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="interest" size="12" title="textfield"  pattern="([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+"  >
                %
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of Years for Loan:</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="years" size="12" title="textfield" pattern="([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+"  >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="button" class="auto-style3" onClick="calculate();" value="Calculate">
              <br />
                <br />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <b>Your Payment Information</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monthly Payment Amount:</td>
            <td>$ <input type="text" name="payment" size="12" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Payment Amount:</td>
            <td>$ <input type="text" name="total" size="12" readonly  ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Interest Payments:</td>
            <td>$ <input type="text" name="totalinterest" size="12" readonly /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="reset" class="auto-style3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">

function calculate() {

var principal = document.loaninfo.principal.value;
var months_in_year = 12
var interest = document.loaninfo.interest.value / 100 / months_in_year;
var payments = document.loaninfo.years.value * months_in_year;
var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
var monthval = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

if (!isNaN(monthval) &&
    (monthval != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
    (monthval != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {

    document.loaninfo.payment.value = round(monthval);
    document.loaninfo.total.value = round(monthval * payments);
    document.loaninfo.totalinterest.value = round((monthval * payments) - principal);
}

else {
    document.loaninfo.payment.value = "";
    document.loaninfo.total.value = "";
    document.loaninfo.totalinterest.value = "";
}

function round(x) {
return Math.round(x*100)/100;
}

function jsDecimals(e) {

var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
var key = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
if (key != null) {
    key = parseInt(key, 10);
    if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 96 || key > 105)) {
        if (!jsIsUserFriendlyChar(key, "Decimals")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (evt.shiftKey) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}

form.onsubmit = function () {
return textarea.value.match(/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/);
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe because of the `interest===0` section? It sets everything to empty...

Comment: Whoops, that was my old code. Updated. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: monthval will be `NaN` - therefore the else code, which clears the values, gets run

Answer (score 4):

When you put 0 you are getting

```
var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments); // 1 
var monthval = principal * x * interest / (x - 1);  //NaN  because 1-1 in fraction is 0 so it returns 0/0 and it's NaN
```

you can change you code to be like this:

```
if (interest===0){   
var monthval = (principal)/(months_in_year);
 } else {
var monthval = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);
 }
```

Working Version: http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/ZpypdA

feel free to change it to be like what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works great now! Sorry, I can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this section of code.

```
else if (interest == 0) {
    document.loaninfo.payment.value = "";
    document.loaninfo.total.value = "";
    document.loaninfo.totalinterest.value = "";
}
```

When the interest is 0, you are setting the values of all your output boxes to an empty string.

You should replace the RHS of the assignment.

Comment: That was my old code, but I fixed it. It's still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you logged your calculated interest value into console?